# Checking a List of Tuples for the exact contents of the Tuples

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples set up as such:

```cs
vars.int1 = 0;
vars.int2 = 0;
vars.int3 = 0;

vars.tList = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>> {
  Tuple.Create(233, 65, 0),
  Tuple.Create(143, 212, 1)
};
```

There are many more tuples in the list, but this will do as an example. `int1`, `int2`, and `int3` get updated constantly in another part of the file and are only here for this example.
Later on in the file, I want to check if the list contains a tuple with exact values. I have tried doing this via

```cs
if (vars.tList.Contains(Tuple(int1, int2, int3))) { }
```

but this would return an error that Tuple is wrongly used as a variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have variables called `int1`, `int2` and `int3`? It would really help if you'd create a [mcve] rather than just showing us *bits* of code. (You may just be looking for `Tuple.Create`, but it's hard to tell without a complete example.)

Comment: do you refer to `Tuple`-**class**, or a `ValueTuple`, which is a **struct**?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I did use Tuple.Create to create my tuples in the list. I do not think that I can share a reproducible example, as what I'm making is a script for the application [LiveSplit](https://github.com/LiveSplit/LiveSplit).

Comment: well, there is nothing that `Tuple(int1, ...)` could resolve to. Did you intent to create a new tuple and check if in your exists there´s one that matches the three values? Something like `if (vars.tList.Contains(Tuple.Create(int1, int2, int3)))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a custom class then please share that definition. Otherwise, maybe this will help:

```
int int1 = 0, int2 = 0, int3 = 0;

List<Tuple<int, int, int>> vars = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>()
{
    new Tuple<int, int, int> (233, 65, 0),
    Tuple.Create(143, 212, 1)
};

vars.Add(Tuple.Create(int1, int2, int3));

if (vars.Contains(new Tuple<int, int, int>(int1, int2, int3)))
{
    Console.Write("Tuple found");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Tuple NOT found");
}
```

Since your code is missing the correct syntax after "Tuple" it is thinking you are using "Tuple" as a variable.